# Find out if two rigid bodies touch

Tags: objects, rigid-body-simulation

Given two rigid body objects obj1 and obj2, I want to ask for a python function that takes two arguments obj1 and obj2 and returns true if the objects obj1 and obj2 intersect or touch each other or false otherwise.

Comment: there is similar question here, also the 3d printing toolbox in blender has this function

Comment: But I want the function to return true also if they only touch.

Comment: [here is the question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/how-to-check-if-two-meshes-intersect-in-python) if it doesn't answer your question comment back

Comment: Thanks, it would probably also work for me, but I have figured out another, not that complex solution.

Comment: it would really be helpful if you share your solution as an answer in here