# strange artifacts seen in 3D view of script-animated high-poly mesh

Tags: rendering, mesh

I'm animating a high-poly mesh using an algorithm which is supposed to be challenging to visualize. See sect. 8.1 of [this paper](http://geuz.org/gmsh/doc/preprints/gmsh_visu_preprint.pdf). I'm using a [key_block](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36915/5334) method to animate the distortion of a high-poly icosphere, and the image shown below looks weird. Is this an artifact of the 3D view rendering, or is there something just bad about the mesh (which could be quite true)?

Since the application will be technical, and getting surfaces in the right place is important (there will be other things in close proximity), just going to fewer polygons or similar things, are not the kind of answer I can use.

The image was made using n_subdivisions = 7, but I have lowered it to 6 in the script to start with. It is a little resource-heavy and takes about a minute.

Yes the script is a little long, but it's the easiest way to allow others to generate the problem.

[image: fluid sphere mesh poor appearance]

[image: fluid sphere mesh poor appearance another]

```
def get_ico_data(n_subdiv=3, size=1.0, location=(0,0,1.0)):
    """get icosphere data from ops primitive because 
    It's easier than figuring it all out myself"""
    make_ico = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add
    make_ico(subdivisions=n_subdiv, size=size, location=location)
    ico = bpy.context.active_object
    ico_data = ico.data.copy()
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    return ico_data

def make_new_meshobject_from_data(data, name=None, scene=None):
    if scene == None:
        scene = bpy.context.scene
    if name == None:
        name = "bob"
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)
    ob.data = data.copy()
    scene.objects.link(ob)
    ob.select = True
    return ob

def velo1(X, t, T):  # written for convenience, not speed
    """from here: http://geuz.org/gmsh/doc/preprints/gmsh_visu_preprint.pdf"""
    pi, twopi = np.pi, 2.0*np.pi
    g = np.cos(pi * t / T)    
    x, y, z = X.T
    vx = 2.*np.sin(   pi*x)**2 * np.sin(twopi*y)    * np.sin(twopi*z)    * g
    vy =   -np.sin(twopi*x)    * np.sin(   pi*y)**2 * np.sin(twopi*z)    * g
    vz =   -np.sin(twopi*x)    * np.sin(twopi*y)    * np.sin(   pi*z)**2 * g    
    V = np.vstack((vx, vy, vz)).T
    return V

def RK4a(x, t, n, h, F, T):
    for i in range(n):  # written for readability, not speed
        ho2, ho6 = h/2.0, h/6.0
        k1 = F(x[i]         ,  t      , T)
        k2 = F(x[i] + k1*ho2,  t + ho2, T)
        k3 = F(x[i] + k2*ho2,  t + ho2, T)
        k4 = F(x[i] + k3*h  ,  t + h  , T)
        x[i+1] = x[i] + ho6 * (k1 + 2.*(k2 + k3) + k4)
        t += h

import bpy
import numpy as np

pi, twopi = np.pi, 2.0*np.pi
radius, center = 0.15, [0.35, 0.35, 0.35]

ico_data = get_ico_data(n_subdiv=6, size=1.0, location=(0,0,0))
print(len(ico_data.vertices))
for v in ico_data.vertices:
    for i in range(3):
        v.co[i] = radius*v.co[i] + center[i]

X0 = np.array([v.co for v in ico_data.vertices])
print("X0.shape: ", X0.shape)
print("X0: ", X0[:,2].max(), X0[:,2].min())

T = 3.0  # how far to go

n, dt = 601, 0.01
t = 0.

# data using RK4
s1, s2 = X0.shape
X_RK = np.zeros((n+2, s1, s2))
X_RK[0] = X0
RK4a(X_RK, t, n, dt, velo1, T)
ddata_RK = X_RK[:n+1]

X = X0.copy()
data = []
data.append(X.copy())
for i in range(n):
    X += dt * velo1(X, t, T)
    data.append(X.copy())
    t += dt
ddata = np.array(data)

np.save("make_my_dayta7",    ddata   )
np.save("make_my_dayta_RK7", ddata_RK)

ico = make_new_meshobject_from_data(ico_data)
ve = ico.data.vertices
ico.scale = [6.0]*3
ico.location = (0,0,0)
print("ve: ", max([v.co[2] for v in ve]), min([v.co[2] for v in ve]))

ico_RK = make_new_meshobject_from_data(ico_data)
ico_RK.scale = [6.0]*3
ico_RK.location = (6,0,0)

dayta    = np.load("make_my_dayta7.npy"   )
dayta_RK = np.load("make_my_dayta_RK7.npy")

n_frames = dayta.shape[0]
print("hey dayta.shape: ", dayta.shape)

bpy.context.scene.frame_end = n_frames

# From here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36915/5334
## ------- part 2  ---set up keyblocks / shape_keys

for i_frame in range(n_frames):
    block    = ico.shape_key_add(name=str(i_frame), from_mix=False)  # returns a key_blocks member
    block_RK = ico_RK.shape_key_add(name=str(i_frame), from_mix=False)  # returns a key_blocks member

    block.value, block_RK.value = 1.0, 1.0
    block.mute,  block_RK.mute  = True, True 

    for (vert, co) in zip(block.data, dayta[i_frame]):
        vert.co = co

    for (vert, co) in zip(block_RK.data, dayta_RK[i_frame]):
        vert.co = co

    # keyframe off on frame zero
    block.mute, block_RK.mute = True, True
    block.keyframe_insert(data_path='mute', frame=0, index=-1)
    block_RK.keyframe_insert(data_path='mute', frame=0, index=-1)

    block.mute, block_RK.mute = False, False
    block.keyframe_insert(data_path='mute', frame=i_frame + 1, index=-1)
    block_RK.keyframe_insert(data_path='mute', frame=i_frame + 1, index=-1)

    block.mute, block_RK.mute = True, True
    block.keyframe_insert(data_path='mute', frame=i_frame + 2, index=-1)
    block_RK.keyframe_insert(data_path='mute', frame=i_frame + 2, index=-1)
```

Comment: These kind of artefacts are usually caused by either reversed normals or overlapping faces (not necessarily duplicate faces, sometimes just an overlap in the surface of two or more faces).

Without going into detail into the precise kind of deformation you are performing, one quick and dirty solution might be using the remesh modifier (specifically with a smooth  mode and at least 7 octtree division) after every iteration of your script.

Comment: Check for self intersections: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/how-to-check-if-two-meshes-intersect-in-python

Comment: Might mean the faces are distorted,  or tangled (vertex order in a face is critical)

Comment: None of the above. I looked and no self-intersection. These faces are all triangles just changing shape - no change in the topology from the original Blender ops primitive icosphere. One can see it happen in the animation.

Comment: How about you upload one of these meshes in a blendfile (www.pasteall.org allows uploading blend files), and that might help us find the issue

Comment: Script makes mesh for you. No need to cary around heavy blend files.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon about no self-intersection - see @TLousky 's [answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38104/5334) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after running the script and looking the mesh, I can say that this is a clear case of overlapping faces, created due to heavy stretching of triangles on top of each other, especially in the center area:

[image: Overlapping triangles]

You can probably avoid this if you somehow generate more geometry in these heavily stretched areas (perhaps calculate each face's area in each iteration and subdivide any face that's above a certain area?). This will make sure you don't get huge highly stretched tris overlapping each other.

It will be trickier to reduce density in areas that don't need it, though, since in your animation some stretched areas will later have hardly any stretch at all.

Comment: Yikes, that looks horrible!! Now I understand what you mean about intersection. I just checked that the front and back didn't touch each other,  but this is something I couldn't imagine. Thank you @TLousky! OK I"ll follow your suggestion and look for some way to make a dynamic and localized subdivision surface modifier - type algorithm. Wish I could up-vote twice!

Comment: I've added another [question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38115/5334) based on this.