# How to check if two meshes intersect in python with BVH Tree?

Tags: python, mesh

In addition to this discussion:

[How to check if two meshes intersect in python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/how-to-check-if-two-meshes-intersect-in-python)

I would like to know if the new mathutils.bvhtree module may help to detect intersections of two meshes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, [overlap](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/mathutils.bvhtree.html?highlight=bvh#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.overlap) in mathutils.bvhtree does show pairs of polygons that are intersecting if any.

You will have to create 2 bvh trees, for each mesh, using one of the methods given in the api (*from Object, from Bmesh, from Polygons*), then use those as `pairs = bvhA.overlap(bvhB)`

So a basic check would just see if that list is `[]` or something. Or may further use the pairs of poly to do something.

---

Note that there are some limitations

- it does not account for other info, if one obj is inside another, normals etc, only if they touch
- it does not work for coplanar poly well, for example 2 blender default plane objects, one slightly shifted x (not reliable on this)

Comment: For a test I used the standard objects Suzanne and Cone with this code:import bpy
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
scene = bpy.context.scene

Suzanne = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]
Cone = bpy.data.objects["Cone"]

Tree_Suzanne = BVHTree.FromObject(Suzanne, scene, deform = False, \
    render =  False, cage = False, epsilon = 0.01)
    

Tree_Cone  = BVHTree.FromObject(Cone, scene, deform = True, \
    render =  False, cage = False, epsilon = 0.01)
    
overlap_pairs = Tree_Cone.overlap(Tree_Suzanne)

print(len(overlap_pairs)). The result: Always 96 independent of the position of objects ??

Comment: I only used from polygon. Where you have vectors and poly indices. And I used  obj.matrix_world * vector.  And it worked very well. I guess this also goes for bmesh, as there is a bmesh transform (with matrix) that u can use first.

Comment: You are completely right. If I use the bmesh transform it works! Thank you