# BVHTree.overlay doesn't register polygons that are coplanar?

Tags: python, collision

I created two default cubes, and offset one of them by 2m, so that they 'touch' perfectly.
[image: Touching cubes]

Running the following code returns an empty list:

```
def get_contact_polygons(self, obj1, obj2):

    obj1_data = obj1.data
    obj2_data = obj2.data

    # Get a BMesh representation
    bm1 = bmesh.new()  # create an empty BMesh
    bm1.from_mesh(obj1_data)
    bm1.transform(obj1.matrix_world)

    bm2 = bmesh.new()  # create an empty BMesh
    bm2.from_mesh(obj2_data)
    bm2.transform(obj2.matrix_world)

    tree1 = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm1)
    tree2 = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm2)

    # Returns: Returns a list of unique index pairs, the first index referencing tree1, the second referencing tree2.
    return tree1.overlap(tree2)
```

Given that the two faces share exactly the same coordinates, I expected this to return a non-empty list.  Playing around with the epsilon value also didn't help.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From what I know, `overlap` is unreliable for coplanar polygons.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady oh ok, I didn't know that.   Is that something that has been documented somewhere? I couldn't find any other posts related to this when googling.

Comment: I've seen it mentioned e.g. here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45834/60486

Comment: I tried a workaround which involved slightly rotating the mesh - this led to the collision between the objects being identified, however the colliding or touching polygons are not returned in the list of indices, which is incredibly annoying.